# Reload a node override pane from a view selection in another pane

Tags: views, panels

1. I have some nodes tagged with taxonomy terms.
2. I have those nodes in a node page override provided by panels. It displays them as the main content.
3. I also have an exposed dropdown selection list filter of the terms  mentioned on *line 1* above provided by a view.
4. In that same node page override from *line 2* I have the view mentioned on *line 3* in the sidebar.

What I'd like to have happen is when a user selects a different term from the dropdown list it reloads the new node in the main content area.